# ¿Cómo uso un elemento de un array de objetos en otra clase?

Tags: java, array

tengo un problema a la hora de utilizar un array de objetos `Posicion` llamado `posiciones` en una tercera clase que es una ventana (VentanaPrioridades), en la cual quiero jugar con el *nombre*, *color* y *posicion* del mismo.

> Clase Posicion

```
package gestionPrioridades;

import java.awt.Color;

public class Posicion extends VentanaPrioridades {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//Propiedades
protected Color color;
protected String nombreSurfer;
protected int posicion;

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public String getNombreSurfer() {
    return nombreSurfer;
}
public void setNombreSurfer(String nombreSurfer) {
    this.nombreSurfer = nombreSurfer;
}
public int getPosicion() {
    return posicion;
}
public void setPosicion(int posicion) {
    this.posicion = posicion;
}

public Posicion(Color color, String nombreSurfer, int i) {
    this.color = color;
    this.nombreSurfer = nombreSurfer;
    this.posicion = -1;
}
```

}

> Clase main

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import gestionPrioridades.Posicion;
import gestionPrioridades.VentanaPrioridades;

public class main {
public main() {
    //GESTIÓN DE PRIORIDADES        
        VentanaPrioridades prioridades = new VentanaPrioridades();  

            Posicion[] posiciones = new Posicion[4];
        posiciones[0] = new Posicion(Color.black, "Jaime Amán", -1);
        posiciones[1] = new Posicion(Color.BLUE, "Lucas Quintana", -1);
        posiciones[2] = new Posicion(Color.GREEN, "Ana Abatu", -1);
        posiciones[3] = new Posicion(Color.RED, "Amanda Lucas", -1);
    }
```

}

> Clase VentanaPrioridades (donde quiero utilizar los elementos del array del main)

```
package gestionPrioridades;


public class VentanaPrioridades extends JFrame {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new VentanaPrioridades();   
        }
    });

}
public VentanaPrioridades() {
    JLabel lblSurfer1 = new JLabel("AQUI QUIERO METER EL NOMBRE");
```

Comment: El array funciona correctamente. ¿Cuál es tu problema?

Comment: El array funciona, pero quiero sacar los elementos NombreSurfer para añadirlos en la VentanaPrioridades que se encuentra en otra clase. Ahí es donde tengo problema, no sé cómo llevar estos elementos al JLabel.

Comment: No puedes acceder a las propiedades de Posicion desde VentanaPrioriedades, salvo que se las pases desde Posicion. Te incluyo una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

VentanaPrioridades *no tiene acceso* a Posicion. 
Posición sí tiene acceso a VentanaPrioridades, puedes hacerlo mediante **this.super**.

Como no tiene acceso, tendrías que guardar la información de Posicion en VentanaPrioridades. (Pero al hacerlo, no tendría mucho sentido la existencia de Posicion)

¿Por qué Posición sí tiene acceso? Posición extiende VentanaPrioridades. Por eso tiene todas las propiedades y métodos de VentanaPrioridades.

¿Cómo pasarle la información a VentanaPrioridades? En el momento de la construcción. Te describo el Stack de llamadas.

1. Primero se ejecuta new Posicion()
2. Llama al constructor Posicion()
3. El constructor genera VentanaPosiciones() mediante super()
4. VentanaPosiciones() genera JFrame mediante super() (es automático)
5. JFrame se genera.
6. VentanaPosiciones termina de ejecutarse tras el super() de JFrame.
7. Posicion termina de generarse tras el super() de VentanaPosiciones.

Puedes aprovechar para pasar a los constructores las variables. En este caso Posicion puede pasar a VentanaPosiciones el surfer mediante super().

A continuación te dejo el código completo:

> Posicion

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Posicion extends VentanaPrioridades {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  // Propiedades
  protected Color color;
  protected String nombreSurfer;
  protected int posicion;

  public Color getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  public String getNombreSurfer() {
    return nombreSurfer;
  }

  public void setNombreSurfer(String nombreSurfer) {
    this.nombreSurfer = nombreSurfer;
  }

  public int getPosicion() {
    return posicion;
  }

  public void setPosicion(int posicion) {
    this.posicion = posicion;
  }

  public Posicion(Color color, String nombreSurfer, int i) {
    super(color, nombreSurfer, i);
    this.color = color;
    this.nombreSurfer = nombreSurfer;
    this.posicion = -1;
  }
}
```

> Ventana prioridades

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class VentanaPrioridades extends JFrame {

  /**
   * 
   */

  protected Color color;
  protected String nombreSurfers;
  protected int posicion;


  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new VentanaPrioridades();   
        }
    });
  }

  public VentanaPrioridades(Color color, String nombreSurfers, int posicion) {
    this.color = color;
    this.nombreSurfers = nombreSurfers;
    this.posicion = posicion;
    crearJFrame();
  }

  public VentanaPrioridades() {
    crearJFrame();
  }

  private void crearJFrame() {
    JLabel lblSurfer1 = new JLabel(nombreSurfers);
  }
}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], considera editar y agregar una explicación a tu codigo

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no entiendo dónde debo definir entonces el array de posiciones. Si me pudieras explicar eso te lo agradecería. A parte tengo un main y dos constructores de ventana junto a un jframe, ¿para qué tanto método?

Comment: Te respondo en varios comentarios, que si, no me entra...

Comment: A grandes rasgos, Main abre la aplicación, que abre cuatro JFrame de tipo Posicion (el usuario ve cuatro ventanas). Main tiene su clase main para que puedas arrancarla, y Posicion tiene su main para que pueda generar el JFrame.

Comment: Por otro lado. Los constructores tienen que ver con cómo funciona la herencia en Java.

Comment: Cuando mandas generar Posicion, internamente pasa lo siguiente:
 1. Posicion mandas generar VentanaPrioridades
 2. A su vez, VentanaPrioridades manda generar JFrame.
 3. JFrame se genera.
 4. Una vez generado JFrame, VentanaPrioridades se termina de generar. 
 5. Una vez generado VentanaPrioridades se termina de generar Posicion

Comment: Cuando haces new Posicion(Color.black, "Jaime Amán", -1), internamente estas usando el constructor Posicion. Ahora, para que le llegue a VentanaPrioridades la información, tienes que llamar a super(color, surfer, posicion), que usa el constructor VentanaPrioridades(Color, String, Integer)

Comment: En definitiva, VentanaPrioridades tiene que guardar la información dentro de ella, no puede acceder a la información de Posicion, porque es una clase hija, no tiene forma de acceder a ella.

Comment: Y para que le llegue y pueda guardarla, tienes que pasarla por un constructor. Que es lo mismo que haces para crear Posicion.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para que lo tengas más claro ahí arriba. Espero que te sirva. Cualquier cosa más pregúntame.